# Asp.Net build AnyCPU or X64 compilation

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

To deploy ASP.Net web application in a 64 bit IIS 7 web server, Should i compile in x64 or Any CPU mode. I know that both is going to work but is there any performance impact on choosing one over the other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only compile for x64-only if you absolutely need it. There shouldn't be any noticeable performance issues.

Comment: Do you know in what scenario we need to do it?

Comment: @user841683 if you have a dependency on an unmanaged dll compiled for x64.